# Selenium - How to handle Microsoft Teams - We're sorry—we've run into an issue

Tags: selenium, exception, webdriver

I'm getting element not interactable exception. After click on "Skip Setup", msteams homepage is not displayed. It is throwing an exception sometimes.

please help me guys.
[please check the screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3deip.jpg)

Comment: Absolutely unclear.

Comment: can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

```
    //enter email id
    d.findElement(By.id("i0116")).sendKeys("enter email id");

    //click next 
    d.findElement(By.id("idSIButton9")).click();

    //enter pwd 
    d.findElement(By.id("i0118")).sendKeys("enter pwd");
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    //click sign in 
    d.findElement(By.id("idSIButton9")).click();

    //Your organisation needs more information to keep your account secure -> click next 
    d.findElement(By.id("idSubmit_ProofUp_Redirect")).click();

    //click skip setup 
    d.findElement(By.linkText("Skip setup")).click();

    //Do this to reduce the number of times you are asked to sign in. -> click yes 
    d.findElement(By.id("idSIButton9")).click();
    d.findElement(By.id("idSubmit_ProofUp_Redirect")).click();

    d.findElement(By.linkText("Skip setup")).click();
```

After skip setup, home page is not displayed, it is showing element not interactable exception